# count que cuente los diferentes registros de un mismo campo y de el resultado con un alias

Tags: mysql

Necesito realizar un `count` donde me cuente cada registro de un campo este campo solo tiene 3 estados y cuente cada estado y lo muestre en cada alias cada estado. y este es agrupado por fecha, ciudad y cliente.

este es el código

```
(select  COUNT(*) where nom_estadog='5') AS Entrega,
(select  COUNT(*) where nom_estadog='6') AS Devolucion,
(select  COUNT(*) where nom_estadog='3') AS Pendientes,
         COUNT(*) AS Total
       FROM generalbtl where  fec_planillar BETWEEN '2019-02-14' AND '2019-02-14'
       GROUP BY fec_planillar, nom_ciudadd, nom_remitente;
```

adjunto imagen

[image: count no cuenta cada estada]

Comment: Pásanos la base de datos en SQL y el resultado que quieres alcanzar, a ver si a nosotros nos sale. Edita la pregunta y será un placer ayudarte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo con [`CASE ... WHEN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case), que servirá para aumentar uno al contador solamente cuando se cumpla el criterio requerido en cada caso:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(CASE WHEN nom_estadog='5'  THEN  1 END) AS Entrega,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN nom_estadog='6'  THEN  1 END) AS Devolucion,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN nom_estadog='3'  THEN  1 END) AS Pendientes,
    COUNT(*) AS Total
FROM generalbtl 
WHERE fec_planillar BETWEEN '2019-02-14' AND '2019-02-14'
GROUP BY fec_planillar, nom_ciudadd, nom_remitente;
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias amigo por la ayuda me funciono.

Answer (score 0):

lo que podrias hacer  es crear un campo nombre estado ponerle los nombres a cada uno ' pendiente' , ' entrega', etc y luego hacer lo siguiente

select cliente,ciudad,fecha,nombre,  COUNT(nom_estadog)
from generalbtl
group by  cliente,fecha,ciudad, nombre